# PerspectiveTransform.js добавить две точки для трансформирования

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Решил использовать [Вот этот плагин](https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js/tree/master), но он использует трансформацию изображения по 4 точкам, а мне нужно по 6.

Так должна проходить трансформация:

[image]

а так она происходит сейчас:

[image]

Я изменил код в `drag_points.html` из папки `\PerspectiveTransform.js-master\examples` (то, что изменял, пометил комментарием).
 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n8j4880/) (но на *фидле* почему-то не работает)

```
      <div id="container"><img class="backofthis" alt="qq" height="300">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="pt tl"></div>
        <div class="pt tr"></div>
        <div class="pt bl"></div>
        <div class="pt br"></div>
        <div class="pt bc"></div><!--i add this -->
        <div class="pt tc"></div><!--i add this -->
    </div>
    <script>
        var container = $("#container");
        var img = $(".img");
        var pts = $(".pt");
        var IMG_WIDTH = 512;
        var IMG_HEIGHT = 512;


        var transform = new PerspectiveTransform(img[0], IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, true);
        var tl = pts.filter(".tl").css({
            left : transform.topLeft.x,
            top : transform.topLeft.y
        });
        var tr = pts.filter(".tr").css({
            left : transform.topRight.x,
            top : transform.topRight.y
        });
        var bl = pts.filter(".bl").css({
            left : transform.bottomLeft.x,
            top : transform.bottomLeft.y
        });
        var br = pts.filter(".br").css({
            left : transform.bottomRight.x,
            top : transform.bottomRight.y
        });
        var tc = pts.filter(".tc").css({ /*i add this*/
            left : transform.topCenter.x,
            top : transform.topCenter.y
        });
        var bc = pts.filter(".bc").css({ /*i add this*/
            left : transform.bottomCenter.x,
            top : transform.bottomCenter.y
        });            
        var target;
        var targetPoint;

        function onMouseMove(e) {
            targetPoint.x = e.pageX - container.offset().left - 20;
            targetPoint.y = e.pageY - container.offset().top - 20;
            target.css({
                left : targetPoint.x,
                top : targetPoint.y
            });

            // check the polygon error, if it's 0, which mean there is no error
            if(transform.checkError()==0){
                transform.update();
                img.show();
            }else{
                img.hide();
            }
        }

        pts.mousedown(function(e) {
            target = $(this);

           /*i change this*/ targetPoint = target.hasClass("tl") ? transform.topLeft : target.hasClass("tr") ? transform.topRight : target.hasClass("bl") ? transform.bottomLeft : target.hasClass("br") ? transform.bottomRight : target.hasClass("tc") ? transform.topCenter : transform.bottomCenter ;/*i change this*/
            onMouseMove.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
            $(window).mousemove(onMouseMove);
            $(window).mouseup(function() {
                $(window).unbind('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Изменяю PerspectiveTransform.js

```
(function (define) {
    define(function(){

function PerspectiveTransform(element, width, height, useBackFacing){

    this.element = element;
    this.style = element.style;
    this.computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.useBackFacing = !!useBackFacing;

    this.topLeft = {x: 0, y: 0};
    this.topRight = {x: width, y: 0};
    this.bottomLeft = {x: 0, y: height};
    this.bottomRight = {x: width, y: height};
    this.topCenter = { x:width/2, y: 0};/*i add this*/
    this.bottomCenter = { x: width/2, y: height };/*i add this*/
}

PerspectiveTransform.useDPRFix = false;
PerspectiveTransform.dpr = 1;

PerspectiveTransform.prototype = (function(){

    var app = {
        stylePrefix: ''
    };

    var _transformStyleName;
    var _transformDomStyleName;
    var _transformOriginDomStyleName;

    var aM = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]];
    var bM = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    function _setTransformStyleName(){
        var testStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
        app.stylePrefix =
            'webkitTransform' in testStyle ? 'webkit' :
            'MozTransform' in testStyle ? 'Moz' :
            'msTransform' in testStyle ? 'ms' :
            '';
        _transformStyleName = app.stylePrefix + (app.stylePrefix.length>0?'Transform':'transform');
        _transformOriginDomStyleName = '-'+app.stylePrefix.toLowerCase()+'-transform-origin';
    }


    // Check the distances between each points and if there is some points with the distance lequal to or less than 1 pixel, then return true. Otherwise return false;
    function _hasDistancesError(){
        var lenX = this.topLeft.x - this.topRight.x;
        var lenY = this.topLeft.y - this.topRight.y;
        if(Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;
        lenX = this.bottomLeft.x - this.bottomRight.x;
        lenY = this.bottomLeft.y - this.bottomRight.y;
        if(Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;
        lenX = this.topLeft.x - this.bottomLeft.x;
        lenY = this.topLeft.y - this.bottomLeft.y;
        if(Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;
        lenX = this.topRight.x - this.bottomRight.x;
        lenY = this.topRight.y - this.bottomRight.y;
        if( Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;
        lenX = this.topLeft.x - this.bottomRight.x;
        lenY = this.topLeft.y - this.bottomRight.y;
        if( Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;
        lenX = this.topRight.x - this.bottomLeft.x;
        lenY = this.topRight.y - this.bottomLeft.y;
        if( Math.sqrt(lenX * lenX +  lenY * lenY)<=1) return true;

        return false;
    }

    // Get the determinant of given 3 points
    function _getDeterminant(p0, p1, p2){
        return p0.x * p1.y + p1.x * p2.y + p2.x * p0.y - p0.y * p1.x - p1.y * p2.x - p2.y * p0.x;
    }

    // Return true if it is a concave polygon or if it is backfacing when the useBackFacing property is false. Otehrwise return true;
    function _hasPolyonError(){
        var det1 = _getDeterminant(this.topLeft, this.topRight, this.bottomRight);
        var det2 = _getDeterminant(this.bottomRight, this.bottomLeft, this.topLeft);
        if(this.useBackFacing){
            if(det1*det2<=0) return true;
        }else{
            if(det1<=0||det2<=0) return true;
        }
        var det1 = _getDeterminant(this.topRight, this.bottomRight, this.bottomLeft);
        var det2 = _getDeterminant(this.bottomLeft, this.topLeft, this.topRight);
        if(this.useBackFacing){
            if(det1*det2<=0) return true;
        }else{
            if(det1<=0||det2<=0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkError(){
        if(_hasDistancesError.apply(this)) return 1; // Points are too close to each other.
        if(_hasPolyonError.apply(this)) return 2; // Concave or backfacing if the useBackFacing property is false
        return 0; // no error
    }

    function update() {
        var width = this.width;
        var height = this.height;

        //  get the offset from the transfrom origin of the element
        var offsetX = 0;
        var offsetY = 0;
        var offset = this.computedStyle.getPropertyValue(_transformOriginDomStyleName);
        if(offset.indexOf('px')>-1){
            offset = offset.split('px');
            offsetX = -parseFloat(offset[0]);
            offsetY = -parseFloat(offset[1]);
        }else if(offset.indexOf('%')>-1){
            offset = offset.split('%');
            offsetX = -parseFloat(offset[0]) * width / 100;
            offsetY = -parseFloat(offset[1]) * height / 100;
        }

        //  magic here:
        var dst = [this.topLeft, this.topRight, this.bottomLeft, this.bottomRight, this.topCenter, this.bottomCenter];/*i add this*/
        var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            aM[i][0] = aM[i+4][3] = i & 1 ? width + offsetX : offsetX;
            aM[i][1] = aM[i+4][4] = (i > 1 ? height + offsetY : offsetY);
            aM[i][6] = (i & 1 ? -offsetX-width : -offsetX) * (dst[i].x + offsetX);
            aM[i][7] = (i > 1 ? -offsetY-height : -offsetY) * (dst[i].x + offsetX);
            aM[i+4][6] = (i & 1 ? -offsetX-width : -offsetX) * (dst[i].y + offsetY);
            aM[i+4][7] = (i > 1 ? -offsetY-height : -offsetY) * (dst[i].y + offsetY);
            bM[i] = (dst[i].x + offsetX);
            bM[i + 4] = (dst[i].y + offsetY);
            aM[i][2] = aM[i+4][5] = 1;
            aM[i][3] = aM[i][4] = aM[i][5] = aM[i+4][0] = aM[i+4][1] = aM[i+4][2] = 0;
        }
        var kmax, sum;
        var row;
        var col = [];
        var i, j, k, tmp;
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++)  col[i] = aM[i][j];
            for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                row = aM[i];
                kmax = i<j?i:j;
                sum = 0.0;
                for(var k = 0; k < kmax; k++) sum += row[k] * col[k];
                row[j] = col[i] -= sum;
            }
            var p = j;
            for(i = j + 1; i < 8; i++) {
                if(Math.abs(col[i]) > Math.abs(col[p])) p = i;
            }
            if(p != j) {
                for(k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                    tmp = aM[p][k];
                    aM[p][k] = aM[j][k];
                    aM[j][k] = tmp;
                }
                tmp = arr[p];
                arr[p] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
            if(aM[j][j] != 0.0) for(i = j + 1; i < 8; i++) aM[i][j] /= aM[j][j];
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) arr[i] = bM[arr[i]];
        for(k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            for(i = k + 1; i < 8; i++) arr[i] -= arr[k] * aM[i][k];
        }
        for(k = 7; k > -1; k--) {
            arr[k] /= aM[k][k];
            for(i = 0; i < k; i++) arr[i] -= arr[k] * aM[i][k];
        }

        var style = 'matrix3d(' + arr[0].toFixed(9) + ',' + arr[3].toFixed(9) + ', 0,' + arr[6].toFixed(9) + ',' + arr[1].toFixed(9) + ',' + arr[4].toFixed(9) + ', 0,' + arr[7].toFixed(9) + ',0, 0, 1, 0,' + arr[2].toFixed(9) + ',' + arr[5].toFixed(9) + ', 0, 1)';

        //A fix for firefox on retina display, require setting PerspectiveTransform.useDPRFix to true and update the PerspectiveTransform.dpr with the window.devicePixelRatio
        if(PerspectiveTransform.useDPRFix) {
            var dpr = PerspectiveTransform.dpr;
            style = 'scale(' + dpr + ',' + dpr + ')perspective(1000px)' + style + 'translateZ('+ ((1 - dpr) * 1000) + 'px)';
        }

        // use toFixed() just in case the Number became something like 3.10000001234e-9
        return this.style[_transformStyleName] = style;

    }

    _setTransformStyleName();

    app.update = update;
    app.checkError = checkError;

    return app;


})();


        return PerspectiveTransform;
    });
}(typeof define === "function" && define.amd ? define : function (app) {
    window["PerspectiveTransform"] = app();
}));
```

что мне нужно изменить в этой функции? Ведь, как я понял, что я сделал всю работу зря, если я не изменил эту ф-цию, но я не понимаю, что мне нужно, чтобы изменить здесь?

```
    var dst = [this.topLeft, this.topRight, this.bottomLeft, this.bottomRight, this.topCenter, this.bottomCenter];/*i add this*/
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    aM[i][0] = aM[i+4][3] = i & 1 ? width + offsetX : offsetX;
    aM[i][1] = aM[i+4][4] = (i > 1 ? height + offsetY : offsetY);
    aM[i][6] = (i & 1 ? -offsetX-width : -offsetX) * (dst[i].x + offsetX);
    aM[i][7] = (i > 1 ? -offsetY-height : -offsetY) * (dst[i].x + offsetX);
    aM[i+4][6] = (i & 1 ? -offsetX-width : -offsetX) * (dst[i].y + offsetY);
    aM[i+4][7] = (i > 1 ? -offsetY-height : -offsetY) * (dst[i].y + offsetY);
    bM[i] = (dst[i].x + offsetX);
    bM[i + 4] = (dst[i].y + offsetY);
    aM[i][2] = aM[i+4][5] = 1;
    aM[i][3] = aM[i][4] = aM[i][5] = aM[i+4][0] = aM[i+4][1] = aM[i+4][2] = 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: последний абзац текста (начиная со слов «Ведь, как я понял») весьма сложно понять.

Answer (score 1):

Для Top Middle Point: https://jsbin.com/rulovunome/1/edit?js,output
Не нужно изменять библиотеку
Горизонтальное перемещение: https://jsbin.com/lisiqiduco/edit?js,output

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно что бы Top Middle Point изменяла изображение не по высоте, а так же трансформила его. Т.е. что бы top left и top right оставались на месте, а Top Middle опускалась вниз/лево/право изменяя изображение.

Comment: Изменил ответ, посмотрите новый вариант, так?

Comment: Даже как то не удобно, но почти то что нужно, смотрите, когда вы перемещаете Top Middle Point то и top left и top right перемещаются тоже, а мне нужно что бы они оставались на месте, а двигалсь только Top Middle и трансформировала изображение

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы Top Left и Top Right были оторванными от изображения? Или чтобы Top Middle реализовывала механизм Skew?

Comment: Посмотрите на последнюю картинку в моем вопросе, вот что мне нужно, т.е. я могу например опустить центральную точку не зависимо от других точек, и каждую из точек я могу перемещать, не зависимо от других, и при этом перемещении будет проходить трансформация

Comment: К сожалению могу только натолкнуть на решение, сам не возьмусь делать, т.к долго. Насколько я понял, вам нужен warp эффект как в photoshop. Есть [похожая реализация](http://persistent.info/web-experiments/distortion/)

Comment: нет, не warp эффект, а трансформация по 6 точкам

Comment: А в какой программе Вы сделали изображение? Есть такой метод, может он Вам подойдет, называется Radial Distortion Methods